# Maven systemPath dependency not added to Class-Path in manifest

Tags: java, maven, jar

My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spt</groupId>
    <artifactId>astra</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.spt.buket_3_wifi.desktop.Main</mainClass>sta
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It compiles successfully, both dependencies log4j-1.2.17.jar and javafx-2.2.3.jar are copied to lib folder. The problem is that lib/javafx-2.2.3.jar doesn't included in Class-Path in jar manifest file, so I unable to run it. MANIFEST.MF is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: karasev
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_40
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.1.0
Main-Class: com.spt.buket_3_wifi.desktop.Main
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

As you can see, only lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar is added. What's the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You may try this approach:

```
...[truncated]...
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.spt.buket_3_wifi.desktop.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>lib/javafx-2.2.3.jar</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
</configuration>
...[truncated]...
```

But this is not necessary for JavaFX library as it's already in JVM classpath.